# What changes are to made in httd.config so that the PHP file can be accessed from different network

Tags: php, xampp

What changes are to made in **httd.config** file so that the PHP files can be accessed from different networks in xampp?

Comment: do you mean : accessed from IP different than localhost ?

Comment: Yes from a different IP than localhost

Answer (score 0):

You should made the update like this 

listen *:80 
and restart your Apache server

Comment: try to ping your server from the client, it may be a network issue

Comment: that means that your have some issues with your network :( you should correct this before going further

Comment: But the server guy is able to ping me successfully on public ip address, but i am not able to ping him

Comment: verify your proxy settings on client side